Why can I sometimes assign to a variable in one function and print it in another?
I don't understand why this code works as it works. Maybe I don't understand what functions and namespaces in Python really are?
Example 1:
def f1():
    a = 1
    f2()

def f2():
    print(a)

a = 0
f1()

Code above returns 0.
Example 2:
def f1():
    a = 1
    def f2():
        print(a)
    f2()

a = 0
f1()

Code above returns 1.
What's the difference?

the second example is a closure

It seems that you do understand the concept of namespaces but can't convince yourself of it. I haven't read this particular article in depth, but you had all the terms needed to research this

While this isn't an exact duplicate, this question explains some details about variable scoping and closures that addresses the behavior you're seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550211/how-do-variables-from-an-outer-scope-get-evaluated-in-nested-functions

sort of dupe Why aren't python nested functions called closures?

This will also help https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

In example 1 f2 uses global a, but in example 2 it uses a from f1 function scope because f2 is a nested function. In other words the difference in variable scope. You can about it here

Specifically, the scope in which f2 is defined determines what the free variable a refers to in each case.

In f2, Python will look up the variable a in two places: the body of f2 & the global scope (the scope with zero indents). a == 0, because a is not defined inside f2 but is defined in the global scope. The a = 1 expression in f1 does nothing, because it creates a new, different variable also named a, but strictly within the scope of f1 instead. This behavior makes separation of code much easier, but it can be overidden with the global keyword:
>>> a = 0
>>> def incr():
...     global a
...     a = 1
...
>>> incr()
>>> print(a)
1

(Disclaimer: it is generally considered bad practice to use global, as using it too frequently tends to create hard-to-debug functions.)
In the second example, the same rules apply, with a mild twist: f2 is being bound within the body of f1, so it performs lookups in f2, f1, and the global scope, in that order. f2 looks up a in f2 and doesn't find anything. f2 looks up a in f1, finds a=1, and returns a. f2 does not look up a in the global scope, because it already found a in f1.

The lookup rule is always the same: free variables refer to the variable of the same name in the closest enclosing scope. In the first example, there just isn't any non-local scope between the local scope of f2 and the global scope.
